# Serial communication with vb.net and arduino

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, arduino-uno

I need a quick and simple way to receive data from my arguing to verify that the data that it is recieving is correct. And to receive 1 integer back. The integer is max 2 characters. However I need to receive multiple bits of data to verify the information.

I've searched the web and all the solutions I've found either don't work or I can't seem to make it work.

Any suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It seems by just using

SerialPort.ReadLine()

That it is returning the values I want.